# getLeft() returning wrong value

Tags: java, android, imageview, coordinates

I've tried to print an ImageView's position in the code by the method getLeft(), just to see if it was returning the right value (which was 80), and logcat returned 192.

```
    ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/image1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:src="@drawable/image1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"/>
```

print command :

```
   public void onWindowFocusChanged (boolean hasFocus){
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if(hasFocus){
        a = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image1);
        Log.v(LOGS, "image a = " + a.getLeft());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `getLeft()` return its value in px. But you have the margin in dp.

```
android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
```